# Can't Retrieve Images With stylesheet_directory

Tags: php, css, wordpress, adobe-brackets

I have three images that I would like to be retrieved on a Wordpress theme I am working on. Yet, none of the images are actually being retrieved. Here is my code as of now. I tried get_stylesheet_directory_uri() as well (which didn't help).

```
 <div class="col-md-4"> <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/Assets/imgs/BlogReferral" alt = "Design"> 
 </div><!-- End Col --> <div class = "col-md-4"> <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/Assets/imgs/InstagramReferral" alt = "Code">
 </div><!-- End Col -->
   <div class = "col-md-4">
          <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/Assets/imgs/ContactReferral" alt = "Design">
 </div><!-- End Col -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function : `get_template_directory_uri()` function.
Image path will be : YOUR_THEME_FOLDER/Assets/imgs/IMAGE_NAME

```
 <div class="col-md-4"> <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/Assets/imgs/BlogReferral" alt = "Design"> 
         </div><!-- End Col --> <div class = "col-md-4"> <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/Assets/imgs/InstagramReferral" alt = "Code">
         </div><!-- End Col -->
           <div class = "col-md-4">
                  <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/Assets/imgs/ContactReferral" alt = "Design">
         </div><!-- End Col -->
```

If you use **Child Theme**. then you need to use function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

image path will be : YOUR_CHILD_THEME/Assets/imgs/IMAGE_NAME

```
<div class="col-md-4"> <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/Assets/imgs/BlogReferral" alt = "Design"> 
         </div><!-- End Col --> <div class = "col-md-4"> <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/Assets/imgs/InstagramReferral" alt = "Code">
         </div><!-- End Col -->
           <div class = "col-md-4">
                  <img class = "img-responsive center-block" src ="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/Assets/imgs/ContactReferral" alt = "Design">
         </div><!-- End Col -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still doesn't retrieve the images though!

Comment: Are you using child theme? @mayaroy

Comment: I am not using a child theme @vrajesh

Comment: Ok great. For that you need to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). @mayaroy